# Illegal Instruction when reading PCD/PLY files readHeader()

Tags: ros, pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**EDIT** I've narrowed down the issue to reading of PCD/PLY files, so the question has basically changed...

I have been stuck on this issue for days, and finally I've given up and decided to ask for help:

I am trying to run a variation of [my_pcl_tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl/Tutorials), but instead of receiving a point cloud via subscription, I am still setting up a subscriber, but then [reading the cloud from a pcb file](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/reading_pcd.php) and then publishing it (via a message forwarder node to avoid sub/pub of the same topic on a single node) on the same topic I am subscribing to. Here is my main():

```
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  // Initialize ROS
  ros::init (argc, argv, "my_pcl_tutorial");

  // Load from file
   pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr pcloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
  //sensor_msgs::PointCloud2::Ptr pcloud(new sensor_msgs::PointCloud2);
  if ( pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZ> ("/home/user/Documents/table_scene_lms400.pcd", *pcloud) == -1) // load the file
  {
    std::cout << "Couldn't read file!\n";
    return (-1);
  }
  std::cout << "Loaded " << pcloud->points.size () << " points." << std::endl;

  //set up publishers and subscribers
  ros::NodeHandle nh;// = ros::NodeHandle(ros::this_node::getName());
  ros::Duration(5).sleep();
  ros::Publisher pubcloud = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> ("/inputforwarder", 1);
  ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe ("/input", 1, cloud_cb);
  //puboutput = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> ("/output", 1);
  puboutput = nh.advertise<pcl::ModelCoefficients> ("/output", 1);
  ros::Duration(5).sleep();

  //publish cloud
  sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 pc2;
  pcl::toROSMsg(*pcloud, pc2);
  pubcloud.publish(pc2);

  // Spin
  ros::spin ();

  return (0);
}
```

Which gives me the error on my loadPCDFile():

```
Starting program: /home/user/ros_workspace/my_pcl_tutorial/bin/example 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
0x00007ffff6f4b1a1 in pcl17::PCDReader::readHeader(std::string const&, sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >&, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1, 0, 4, 1>&, Eigen::Quaternion<float, 0>&, int&, int&, unsigned int&, int) ()
   from /home/user/ros_workspace/fuerte-unstable-devel/pcl17/lib/libpcl_io.so.1.7
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff6f4b1a1 in pcl17::PCDReader::readHeader(std::string const&, sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >&, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1, 0, 4, 1>&, Eigen::Quaternion<float, 0>&, int&, int&, unsigned int&, int) ()
   from /home/user/ros_workspace/fuerte-unstable-devel/pcl17/lib/libpcl_io.so.1.7
#1  0x00007ffff6f48af4 in pcl17::PCDReader::read(std::string const&, sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >&, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1, 0, 4, 1>&, Eigen::Quaternion<float, 0>&, int&, int) ()
   from /home/user/ros_workspace/fuerte-unstable-devel/pcl17/lib/libpcl_io.so.1.7
#2  0x000000000044e9f4 in pcl17::PCDReader::read<pcl17::PointXYZ> (
this=0x7fffffffd970, file_name=..., cloud=..., offset=0)
at /home/user/ros_workspace/fuerte-unstable-devel/pcl17/include/pcl-1.7/pcl17/io/pcd_io.h:209
#3  0x000000000044af8e in pcl17::io::loadPCDFile<pcl17::PointXYZ> (
file_name=..., cloud=...)
    at /home/user/ros_workspace/fuerte-unstable-devel/pcl17/include/pcl-1.7/pcl17/io/pcd_io.h:544
#4  0x0000000000445afd in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdd38)
at /home/user/ros_workspace/my_pcl_tutorial/src/example.cpp:72
```

which boils down to an issue in readHeader().

It is finding the file just fine, in case you were wondering. I've tried multiple PCD and PLY files, tried different ways of reading the files (using a pcd Reader, built-in ros/pcl pointcloud viewers, etc), but nothing is working. I have updated rosPCL, but that did not help either.

Thanks for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64428/illegal-instruction-when-reading-pcd/ply-files-readheader()/) by [dberm22](https://answers.ros.org/users/4189/dberm22/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2013-06-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try to update your ros-fuerte-perception-pcl (There is a new version out since yesterday I think). I had a similar problem giving me an "Illegal instruction" error. The 1.2.3 version of ros-fuerte-perception-pcl was compiled with differend flags which led to this error.

---

Originally posted by [alex_rockt](https://answers.ros.org/users/5037/alex_rockt/) with karma: 76 on 2013-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alex_rockt](https://answers.ros.org/users/5037/alex_rockt/) on 2013-06-06**:
Try x/i $pc in gdb to see which instruction is causing the SIGILL, for me it was vmovsd

**Comment by [dberm22](https://answers.ros.org/users/4189/dberm22/) on 2013-06-11**:
You are mostly correct. I updated to pcl-1.7 thinking that the changes made to 1.5 would be reflect in 1.7, but they were not. I downloaded the new version of 1.5 from here http://50.28.27.175/repos/building/pool/main/r/ros-fuerte-pcl/ and it worked like a charm. I will update the rest now. Thanks!